# Translate PT_TOUCH injected event into WM_TOUCH event

Tags: c++, winapi

### Is there a way to "translate" PT_TOUCH event to WM_TOUCH event?

**To clarify why I need to do this, please red the text below (not necessary):**

The reason for this question is that I'm using old WINUSER.h in a project in which I'm trying to catch msg parameters from Window callback (These two are tested and work).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)

switch (msg)    {

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {        
        doSomething;
        break; }

    case WM_TOUCH:  {   
        doSomethingElse;
        break;  }
}
```

I'm injecting PT_TOUCH inputs from another project, which has a newer version of WINUSER.h header, that already has the PT_TOUCH implementation. (I'm translating some inputs read by that project into touch events actually). So it looks something like this:

```
POINTER_TOUCH_INFO contact;
ZeroMemory(&contact, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));

InitializeTouchInjection(1, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT); 
memset(&contact, 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));

contact.pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
contact.pointerInfo.pointerId = 0;  
contact.touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
contact.touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE;

contact.orientation = 90; 

contact.pressure = channelPressForce;

contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = ((pressTouch.getTouchX(selected) * 0x7FFF) / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1)); 
contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = ((pressTouch.getTouchY(selected) * 0x7FFF) / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1)); 
                    // defining contact area (I have taken area of 8 x 8 pixel)
contact.rcContact.top = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 4;
contact.rcContact.bottom = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 4;
contact.rcContact.left = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x - 4;
contact.rcContact.right = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x + 4;

contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT | POINTER_FLAG_DOWN;// | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
InjectTouchInput(1, &contact); // Injecting the touch down on screen
printf("SENT TOUCH DOWN EVENT \n");
```

I believe that the code works correctly as I've tried to inject MOUSE events instead with no problems. (Even though I could see the results of MOUSE events on my screen - as if I was clicking - but I cannot see the results of the injected TOUCH events for some reason ).

### Some EXTRA INFO:

Simply updating the project with the newer version of the header is unfortunately not an option (AFAIK).

It doesn't necessarily have to be WM_TOUCH event, It's okay if it's WM_MOUSE event, all I need is support for one extra info (which mouse event has) and Multi-touch support - in this case I'm not sure mouse can handle this.

Comment: If you can't update the headers why not just copy & paste the pertinent structure definitions into your own code?

Comment: Updating the Windows SDK will not (in the vast majority of cases) introduce breaking changes. It is unclear why you believe, that updating the SDK headers were not an option. Mouse messages do support (sort of anyway) multi-touch information. This is used by the system when generating back-compatibility mouse messages for touch input. The information is [stored in the message extra info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages) (the lower 7 bits represent the cursor ID). I'm not sure whether this can be used reliably by client code, though.

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately I don't have access to the whole (old) project structure and am unable to change the SDK it's working with. I forgot to add that apart from multi-touch I also need gesture support - is it doable with just mouse events?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm gonna try that, but I'm very unsure about this solution - won't it miss anything it could be linked to? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: You cannot mix Windows Touch Input and Windows Touch Gestures. A window is either registered to receive `WM_TOUCH` messages, or it can be configured to receive `WM_GESTURE` messages. You can't get both at the same time (unless that changed in Windows 8 or 10).

Comment: Nevermind - I was using old pre-built user32.lib in the project, that's why simply updating the SDK didn't work. Sorry for taking your time and thank you @IInspectable for the suggestion to update SDK, it helped in the end!

Now I can use both WM_TOUCH and PT_TOUCH and there's no need to "translate" anything.

Comment: @IInspectable since you provided the answer in comments I'm fine if you write the answer instead - I will delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no use in it.

Instead upgrade your SDK, as iinspectable suggested and you'll be able to use both WM_TOUCH and PT_TOUCH.

And be sure to double check for pre-built libraries/wrong project settings in your project if upgrading SDK doesn't work as this solved my problem with unresolved external symbols after upgrading project SDK.

Comment: I do remember that I made a work-around , but I no longer have access to the code. So unless someone is forced to use the exact version of SDK (which was my case) this is the correct solution, otherwise there's an option for windows custom events work-around.